# Identify number of rows by id that have sequential values in another column, with the greatest of those values equaling a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2bzoKxbU2gznwwmQpMmjp5/0

(Actual database is Microsoft SQL Server 2014)

Above is a fiddle of what I'm trying to do.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
  id nvarchar(5) NOT NULL,
  year int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,year)
  );
INSERT INTO table1 (id, year) VALUES
  ('A', '2013'),
  ('A', '2014'),
  ('A', '2017'),
  ('A', '2018'),
  ('B', '2016'),
  ('B', '2017'),
  ('B', '2018'),
  ('C', '2016'),
  ('D', '2014'),
  ('D', '2016'),
  ('D', '2018');
```

This is roughly what the data is that I'm working with, where I want to find number of consecutive/sequential records for each id that also contains '2018' in the year column.

My thought process so far has gone like this:

```
select id, count(*)
from table1
group by id;

select main.id,
    case when in_2018.id is not null
        then count(*) 
    else 0
    end
from table1 as main
left join table1 as in_2018
    on in_2018.id = main.id
    and
        in_2018.year = 2018
group by main.id;

/*
    Want a table:
    A | 2
    B | 3
    C | 0
    D | 1

    Count of records that are in a single-step incremental that include 2018     by id
*/
```

Obviously, these don't return sequential rows, just counts that meet the '2018' criteria.

I tried another approach that checks:

```
case when count(*) = max(year) - min(year) +1,
```

In my data example, that works for id B, because all of B's data is sequential, but it doesn't address the broken pattern of the other ids.

Comment: Any particular database? Finding a solution here is probably way easier if you can use some non '92 standard SQL. If so, please tag your question with this database, so we'll know.

Comment: Your fiddle uses MySQL, can we assume you're using MySQL in reality?  If so, version 8+ or 5.x?  *(This is "relatively" simple to solve in anything other than MySQL5.x, which requires nasty unsupported hacks/functionality using variables.)*

Comment: The actual database is SQL Server 2014, sorry about that, will clarify in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you would solve this using `row_number()`:

```
select top (1) id, count(*)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by year) as seqnum
      from table1 t
     ) t
group by id, (year - seqnum)
having sum(case when year = 2018 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
order by count(*) desc;
```

This uses the observation that `year - seqnum` is constant when years are in a sequence.

In databases that don't support window functions, the simplest solution might be a correlated subquery that does the same calculation:

```
select id, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from table1 tt
              where tt.id = t.id and tt.year <= t.year
             ) as seqnum
      from table1 t
     ) t
group by id, (year - seqnum)
having sum(case when year = 2018 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 year only;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2bzoKxbU2gznwwmQpMmjp5/0) is the db<>fiddle.

Comment: That did it perfectly, thanks!

I had been struggling with this for awhile, I don't think I've ever even used calculations in a group by yet, so I will definitely be looking to be smarter about that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I see Gordon beat me to it, and with a query that is quite a bit shorter. But I've come this far, I'd post it anyway. I think the general idea is more or less the same, but mine doesn't depend on any non-standard feature (I think), and I hope I made up for the additional code by adding some comments to make it even longer. ;-)

And each of the subqueries can be run separately so you can see how to 'zoom in' on the result step by step.

```
select
  id,
  max(span) as nr_of_years
from
  ( -- This inner query gives all the valid ranges, but they have to be deduplicates
    -- For instance, it can give B 2017-2018 while there is also B 2016-2018, which has precedence.
    -- That's why the outer query uses max, to get the longest range
    select
      s.id,
      s.year,
      s.otheryear,
      s.span,
      s.rows_in_span
    from
      ( -- Find all possible 'spans' of years between two rows with the same id.
        -- also find how much rows are in that span. They should match.
        select 
          a.id, 
          a.year,
          b.year as otheryear,
          a.year - b.year + 1 as span,
          ( select count(*) from table1 c
            where
              c.id = a.id and
              c.year >= b.year and
              c.year <= a.year) as rows_in_span
        from
          table1 a
          join table1 b on b.ID = a.ID and b.year <= a.year -- like a cross join, but per ID
      ) s
    where
      -- if they are not equal, it means one year is missing between the lowest and highest year in the span
      s.span = s.rows_in_span and
      -- If the difference between the year and 2018 is more than this, this is a range, but it's out of scope
      abs(s.year - 2018) < s.span
  ) f
group by
  f.id
```

In the fiddle you can see it working for Postgres too (You can just toggle between databases, I dumbed down the create statement to allow that):

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aQpVMRYhLXJwfcRcJmY8qZ/1)